# Bootstrap form template is not working well

Tags: php, html, css, forms, bootstrap-4

I have question about bootstrap form template. It isnt working for me. I added files to my website (not launched yet) and nothing happened. And I copied all files so I dont know what is wrong. Do I need change something more in php or html? I just replaced my email and that was all.
Template: https://colorlib.com/wp/template/contact-form-19/

Comment: Saying "it's not working", is almost the least informative problem description you can give. We cannot guess what "isn't working", we need your description to understand the problem.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Try to use the demo code of bootstrap itself: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/components/forms/ 

If this doesn't work either you're missing the css: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: I meant that part. When you sended it. When I added that to web server, Will it work?

Comment: Bcs now when I wanted to send message it saying "Something went wrong. Please try again." And I know its just on my PC, but idk if is this that problem.